# Grid column as a button that performs an action on model's item

Tags: html, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a grid looking like this -

```
@{
                    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.products,
                            rowsPerPage: 40);

                    }
                    @grid.GetHtml(
                                   tableStyle: "gridtable",
                          alternatingRowStyle: "even",
                      columns: grid.Columns(
                                      grid.Column("ProductName", "Product"),
                                      grid.Column("Price", "Price"),
                                      grid.Column("Quantity", "Left:"),
                                      grid.Column("Image", header: "Image", format: @<text><img src="@item.Image" width="250px" height="200px"></img></text>)
  )
                 )
```

I want to add a column that shows a **button for each row** that upon pressing, **reduces a property of the current item** by 1, then pops a message.
How can I do it?

Comment: do you want to reduce the value client-side, or server-side? Either way you need to handle the click event of the button, if it's just client-side then find the HTML element you want to modify and modify it, or if it's server-side, make a HTTP request (either full postback or ajax, as per your need) to and endpoint which will make the amendment to the data. Since you didn't give any real detail of what you're after or which part of the process you're stuck with, it's hard to tell you anything other than this general approach.

Comment: Id like to reduce it in both the client side (data accessed through the DAL) and the (SQL) server side.
Also would there be an easier way to implement this using some existing tool?

Comment: what kind of tool are you thinking of? A "reduce-quantity" plugin? No, it's just some custom logic you have to implement. Unless maybe the WebGrid tool has some methods for manipulating the content, you'd have to read the documentation. Of course the are tools you can use to make the coding simpler / more concise if you wish, such as jQuery or other JS frameworks.